# Convert csv to json - column1 as a key (nested dict)

Tags: python, json, csv

I need `column1` to be used as a `KEY` and its value to be a dict of column2 (as key) & column3 (as value) so that output will become a nested dictonary.

**For example:**

I have a csv file as shown below:

```
customer1,subkey1,val1
customer2,subkey2,val2
customer2,subkey3,val3
customer2,subkey4,val4
customer3,subkey5,val5
customer3,subkey6,val6
```

expecting output to be:

```
{
 customer1: {
   subkey1:val1
   },
 customer2: {
   subkey2:val2,
   subkey3:val3,
   subkey4:val4
   },
 customer3: {
   subkey5:val5,
   subkey6:val6
   }
}
```

I have tried to convert below sample code as per my requirement, but no luck:

```
import csv 
import json 

def csv_to_json(csvFilePath, jsonFilePath):
    jsonArray = []
      
    #read csv file
    with open(csvFilePath, encoding='utf-8') as csvf: 
        #load csv file data using csv library's dictionary reader
        csvReader = csv.DictReader(csvf) 

        #convert each csv row into python dict
        for row in csvReader: 
            #add this python dict to json array
            jsonArray.append(row)
  
    #convert python jsonArray to JSON String and write to file
    with open(jsonFilePath, 'w', encoding='utf-8') as jsonf: 
        jsonString = json.dumps(jsonArray, indent=4)
        jsonf.write(jsonString)
          
csvFilePath = r'data.csv'
jsonFilePath = r'data.json'
csv_to_json(csvFilePath, jsonFilePath)
```

Comment: Is the file sorted by customers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this
worked for me I used the csv.reader for this and changed the variable into a dict object

```
import csv
import json

def csv_to_json(csvFilePath, jsonFilePath):
    jsonDict = {}

    # read csv file
    with open(csvFilePath, encoding='utf-8') as csvf:
        # load csv file data using csv library's dictionary reader
        csvReader = csv.reader(csvf, delimiter=',')
        # convert each csv row into python dict
        for row in csvReader:
            # add this python dict to json array
            if row[0] in jsonDict:
                jsonDict[row[0]][row[1]] = row[2]
           else:
                jsonDict[row[0]] = {row[1]: row[2]}

    # convert python jsonArray to JSON String and write to file
    with open(jsonFilePath, 'w', encoding='utf-8') as jsonf:
        jsonString = json.dumps(jsonDict, indent=4)
        jsonf.write(jsonString)


csvFilePath = r'data.csv'
jsonFilePath = r'data.json'
csv_to_json(csvFilePath, jsonFilePath)
```

output

```
{
"customer1": {
    "subkey1": "val1"
},
"customer2": {
    "subkey2": "val2",
    "subkey3": "val3",
    "subkey4": "val4"
},
"customer3": {
    "subkey5": "val5",
    "subkey6": "val6"
}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```py
import collections
import csv

with open('file.csv') as f:
  reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',')
  dict_1 = collections.defaultdict(dict)
  for row in reader:
    dict_1[row[0]][row[1]] = row[2]

print(dict(dict_1))
```

```
# Output
{
 customer1: {
   subkey1:val1
   },
 customer2: {
   subkey2:val2,
   subkey3:val3,
   subkey4:val4
   },
 customer3: {
   subkey5:val5,
   subkey6:val6
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In this case, `DictReader` doesn't really help you because it gives each row as a dict in the form:

```py
{"column1": "customer1", "column2": "subkey1", "column3": "val1"}
```

So it will actually be simpler to use a regular [`reader`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.reader) and parse manually. You just need to expand existing customers, so it will be helpful to use a [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict):

```py
import csv
import json
from collections import defaultdict

def csv_to_json(csvFilePath, jsonFilePath):
    jsonDict = defaultdict(dict)

    # read csv file
    with open(csvFilePath, encoding='utf-8') as csvf:
        # load csv file data using csv library's reader
        csvReader = csv.reader(csvf)

        # convert each csv row into a list
        for row in csvReader:
            # add this list to json dict
            jsonDict[row[0]][row[1]] = row[2]

    # write python jsonDict to JSON file
    with open(jsonFilePath, 'w', encoding='utf-8') as jsonf:
        json.dump(jsonDict, jsonf, indent=4)
```

Note that the `json` file can be written simpler by using `dump` instead of `dumps`.